# Can i know string localization Language?

Tags: android

I get string from sms message, there is any option to know what lang\local 
I need to select. I need it for checking if text to speech option is available.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It can be easy or hard, depending on the languages. Finding if a string is Hebrew or English is *very* easy, the characters are all different. Finding if a string is English or French is harder, because you need to figure out if words are English or French. Finding if a string is in Spanish or Catalan can be impossible on a short string.